# Web.xml configuration is broken when upgrading to Tomcat 8.5 and Spring 5.1

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat8

I'm upgrading from Tomcat 8.0 to 8.5.87, while upgrading Spring to 5.1.20.RELEASE and it broke my OSGi application. It works if I just downgrade to Tomcat 8.0

It's erroring out when parsing `<listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</Listener>`. Any I verified that spring-web-5.1.20.RELEASE.jar is in the classpath.

Here's the error that and the web.xml

```
Apr 29, 2023 5:41:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 29, 2023 5:41:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 29, 2023 5:41:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase$CombinedEnumeration.inc(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2775)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase$CombinedEnumeration.hasMoreElements(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2760)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getConfigurationFile(LogFactory.java:1366)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:453)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:269)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4950)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:711)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
    at org.cg.dao.webcontainer.tomcat.TomcatWrapper.startWebApp(TomcatWrapper.java:187)
    at org.cg.dao.webcontainer.tomcat.TomcatWrapper.prepareAllWebApps(TomcatWrapper.java:141)
    at org.cg.dao.webcontainer.tomcat.TomcatWrapper.startServer(TomcatWrapper.java:208)
    at org.cg.dao.webcontainer.tomcat.Application.start(Application.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
```

Here's the web.xml

```xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
         version="3.1">
         
    <display-name>App Services</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/application-context.xml,WEB-INF/application-context-websocket.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <absolute-ordering />

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ExecutionTimeFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
                <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>executionTimeFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ExecutionTimeFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RESTServices</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>disable-address-updates</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WebSockets</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/application-context-websocket.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RESTServices</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/services-internal/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WebSockets</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/websockets/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

If I comment out `<listener>` then the error is thrown...

```
Apr 29, 2023 5:46:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 29, 2023 5:46:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter [ExecutionTimeFilter]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase$CombinedEnumeration.inc(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2775)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase$CombinedEnumeration.hasMoreElements(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2760)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getConfigurationFile(LogFactory.java:1366)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:453)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.<init>(GenericFilterBean.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.<init>(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:107)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4976)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:711)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
    at org.cg.dao.webcontainer.tomcat.TomcatWrapper.startWebApp(TomcatWrapper.java:187)
    at org.cg.dao.webcontainer.tomcat.TomcatWrapper.prepareAllWebApps(TomcatWrapper.java:141)
    at org.cg.dao.webcontainer.tomcat.TomcatWrapper.startServer(TomcatWrapper.java:208)
    at org.cg.dao.webcontainer.tomcat.Application.start(Application.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
```

Update: Looks like its calling loader.getResources("commons-logging.properties") but I don't have any commons-logging.properties in my project files.

Comment: Looking at the error stack, why does it seem like org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getConfigurationFile is calling getResources() from org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase instead of org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory?

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8.5.x/java/org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoaderBase.java#L1115

https://github.com/apache/commons-logging/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.java#L1363

Comment: meant to link https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8.5.x/java/org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoaderBase.java#L1005

Comment: LogFactory is trying to load resources from the ClassLoader, which makes sense.